# phonegap ios javascript doesn't work on simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, phonegap

I am new on Xcode and Phonegap. My app is based on the code of this web http://catedralski.com/catedral_app/index.html.

This page for example is essential and I can't get it work on the simulator
http://catedralski.com/catedral_app/climaweb.html

When I run the code on a browser works fine, but when is runned on the IOS Simulator the JS doesn't work.

The path is fine because the CSS and the img are working. 
 The internet connection is working too. The external links work too.
 The script src=cordova.js is added

There is any special setting on the IOS simulator or in the code to check the app on the IOS simulator?

A small detail. I don´t add yet the apple Id and the certificates . Is neccessary to test on the simulator??

Comment: If the simulator works as a real device, yes. It is possible you have to add a developer certificate with the proper provisioning file. Give it a try